# Pre-Requisits for Learning Topology

Tags: self-learning

I am an art student and I think my work could benefit from broadening my horizons on mathematics. I am mostly interested in Topology, but starting from high school mathematics I don't know where to begin learning. Could you give me an order of subjects to learn before starting topology?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a visual taste of topology, try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Topological_Picturebook

Comment: What makes you interested in topology? Going straight from the arts to topology might be a seriously difficult jump. I started learning topology when I realised I needed it to go further in analysis. It's not just "coffee mug = donut", it's as rigorous and (as some would argue - but not me!) "dry" or "mathsy" as any other area of maths

Comment: Note that the difficulty doesn’t come from the pre-reqs but from the mathematical rigour. You don’t need to know anything before taking topology. However, analysis is often the first course taught (and is a direct extension of high school calculus), so you might find that easier as an introduction to college mathematics.

Comment: You need to have completed the four semester calculus sequence with differential equations to develop the mathematical maturity for advanced undergraduate courses. It is best to learn real analysis at the level of a junior level class before learning topology because the ideas of topology are generalizations of those concepts. The bottom line is that you are about two to two and a half years away from studying topology to any depth. This also assumes you took the pre-requisites for calculus in high school.